# JQ: Remove empty arrays from JSON

Tags: json, jq, text-manipulation

I am having trouble deleting all empty arrays from a JSON file with `jq`.

I've tried:

```
walk(if type == "array" then map(select(length > 0)) else . end)
```

which removes empty strings, but the arrays stay in the document. Is there a way to remove the arrays completely?
Thank you for your support.

Comment: Please show us your input json. For more info about asking a question; please read [ask] / [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could walk through using `..`, select everything that is an empty array `[]` and set it to `empty`

```
(.. | select(. == [])) |= empty
```

Edit:

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434407/jq-remove-empty-arrays-from-json#comment122728063_69435180), oguz ismail uses `del()` instead of `|= empty` which is the preferred approach if the empty arrays to be deleted may be located not only in an object `{"a":[]}` but also in a superordinate array (`[[]]`).

```
del(.. | select(. == []))
```

Comment: Or `del(recurse | select(. == []))`.